# Why generics can only detect arrow function in object but not function expression?

Tags: typescript-generics

```js
type C = <
    Methods,
    Attached = (methods: Methods) => void
>(
    options: {
        methods: Methods;
        attached: Attached;
    }
) => any;
    
var Component: C = () => { }
    
Component({
    attached(methods) {
        methods.bbb() // throw ts error
    },
    methods: {
        bbb() { }
    }
})
    
Component({
    attached(methods) {
        methods.bbb() // ok
    },
    methods: {
        bbb: () => { }
    }
})
```

Parameter "methods" in "attach" function should be functions declared in "methods" property, it works only when function is arrow function.
Please tell me why and how to solve it.

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image